# Change the size of a dialog window based on an action in ScriptUI

Tags: javascript, dialog, resize, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

ScriptUI is wonderful, but seems to have some limitations.  I am looking for an ability to dynamically resize a dialog window based on an action taken on one of the controls inside of it, such as an `.onClick()` or `.onShow()` callback.  However, the only way I've seen for the window to be resized is *before* it is drawn on the screen with the `.show()` method.  Once the window has been shown, it appears that there is no way for a control to resize it.  Please tell me I am wrong and there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly based on [Peter Kahrels ScriptUI Guide](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html)

```
var w = new Window ("dialog"); 
var b = w.add('button',undefined,'Click me');
var small = false;
//~ w.onShow = function () {
//~     w.size = {width: 300, height: 400};
//~     } 
b.onClick = function(){
    small = !small;
    if(small == false){
        w.size = {width: 300, height: 400};
    }else{
        w.size = {width: 100, height: 100};
    }
}
w.show();
```

Comment: This is just what I needed!  `w.width` wasn't working except during "show"-time; I didn't realize that the `.size` method works even after the window has been shown.  Thanks a bunch, @fabiantheblind!